# Iterator<Long> :The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Long>

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, socketserver

Now I'm working on Socket Server, and made multi-thread for muliti-clients for a socket.
and Also put each thread of the connection into a HashMap to store the Objects of threads.

Here's the problem: I can't get returned keyset of the HashMap into Iterator.
I initialized the key value as . What's the problem? I have no Idea.

```
HashMap<Long, ClientThread> m_clients;

long m_currentKey;

m_clients.put((Long)m_currentKey, clientThread);

Iterator<Long> itr = m_clients.keySet().iterator(); //error:: Why?
```

[image]

Comment: Look at the type it's talking about: `HTMLDocument.Iterator`. That isn't the same as `java.util.Iterator`. We don't know where `HTMLDocument` comes in, or what imports you've got etc... but that's the problem. If you want more advice, you'll need to create a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the question. You're using the type `HTMLDocument.Iterator`, instead of using `java.util.Iterator`.

Fix your imports.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite clear, [HTMLDocument.Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.Iterator.html) is different from [java.util.Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and is not a generic class. You should always refer to the documentation before asking a question. It seems that the class you really want to use is `java.util.Iterator`. Be careful when using your IDE propositions of import fixes, having such a functionality does not mean you can let the IDE think for you.

Answer (score 1):

In The Top of your class where you have imported the iterator class

```
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;
```

in place of this import below class

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

it will solve your problem